# How can I identify "unused" repositories in Gerrit?

Tags: git, gerrit

How can I identify "unused" repositories in Gerrit? Two examples come to my mind:

- Empty repositories (containing no file).
- No activity for x days since the last write access (git push) to the repository.

Answer (score 1):

Some ideas:

(1) Which tool your Gerrit server uses as repository browser? Gitweb? If you install the [Gerrit-GitBlit plugin](https://github.com/tomaswolf/gerrit-gitblit-plugin) you'll have the GitBlit integrated as the repository browser. It is really cool, much better than Gitweb and... you'll be able to see all repositories orded by the last change!

[image]

(2) Have you tried to search for "status:open AND age:" (time = 4w, 6mon, 1y, etc)  using the Gerrit UI? I know it's not what you're searching for but I think it can be useful to find missed changes and maybe some repositories that are not being used anymore.

Comment: we are using gitweb but we have performance issue in using GitBlit .

Answer (score 0):

Gerrit has a [REST API](https://gerrit-documentation.storage.googleapis.com/Documentation/2.13.5/rest-api.html) which you can use to do what you want. Particularly the [Project API](https://gerrit-documentation.storage.googleapis.com/Documentation/2.13.5/rest-api-projects.html).

You can [get a list of all projects](https://gerrit-documentation.storage.googleapis.com/Documentation/2.13.5/rest-api-projects.html#list-projects) and literate through the list querying various things about the state of its branches.

Comment: if we have several 100 of branch & tags, it will take enough time to parse

Comment: @Jayanth Set it running and go to lunch. This sounds like something you'd run maybe once a year to clean up dead projects. But consider if you have too many open branches.